# Xamarin Localization and binding error

Tags: c#, localization, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have problem with translation binding text. How could I do it that binding item works fine ? I have tried change sequence but still nothing and i dont't have idea what now. Below is my code of list which is part of XAML where i can bind and translate words

This code work fine:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="10" Padding="30" VerticalOptions="Center" >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button  Grid.Row="2"  Text="{resource:TranslateExtension Szukaj}"
                BorderRadius="30"
                BackgroundColor="#80FFFFFF"

                FontSize="18"
                TextColor="#ffe2fb"
                BorderWidth="4"
                BorderColor="#ffe2fb"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>

    <Button  Grid.Row="3"  Text="{resource:TranslateExtension Mapa}"
                BorderRadius="30"
                BackgroundColor="#80FFFFFF"
                FontSize="18"
                TextColor="#ffe2fb"                    
                BorderWidth="4"
                BorderColor="#ffe2fb"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked"/> 
</Grid>
```

But this code not:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="ListaNazw" SeparatorColor="#3d122c" HasUnevenRows="True"
              RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Height,Factor=1,Type=RelativeToParent}"
              RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Property=Width,Factor=1,Type=RelativeToParent}"  ItemSelected="ListaNazw_ItemSelected" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  Padding="5" BackgroundColor="#50FFFFFF">
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{resource:TranslateExtension {Binding nazwa}}" TextColor="#fff2f2" FontSize="17"/>
                            <Label Text="{resource:TranslateExtension {Binding opis}}" TextColor="#ffe5e5" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

List

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ListaNazw.ItemsSource = new List<Listyy>
          {

              new Listyy { nazwa = "Pierwsze Spotkanie", opis="Niech to spotkanie będzie udane" , ema = 1 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Spotkanie Biznesowe", opis = "Zaimponuj swojemu partnerowi", ema = 2 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Spotkanie Towarzyskie", opis = "Make your day", ema = 3 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Pierwsza Randka", opis = "Oczaruj swoją drugą połówkę", ema = 4 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Pierwszy Raz", opis = "Zapewne to będzie wyjątkowe", ema = 5 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Spotkanie", opis = "Luźna rozmowa przy kawie", ema = 6 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Rozrywka", opis = "Czas na chwilę szaleństwa", ema = 7 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Impreza", opis = "Ubierz coś ładnego, my zajmiemy się resztą", ema = 8 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Spacer", opis = "Park, molo? Pozwól sobie pomóc", ema = 9 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Odpoczynek", opis = "Chwila relaksu z pewnością Ci nie zaszkodzi", ema = 10 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Urodziny", opis = "Zrób niespodziankę swoim bliskim", ema = 11 },
              new Listyy { nazwa = "Czas wolny", opis = "Znajdziemy Ci idealne miejsce", ema = 12 },

          };
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see code where you set `ItemSource` to your `ListView` and data model for your `ListView`, unlike binding directly binding between data and view, the binding for item is cloned for every item in the `ListView`, and data bindings that have been set on the template are transferred to the individual clones.

I think you can consider it as a binding model for each item. You can refer to [Bindings and Collections](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/#Bindings_and_Collections) to implement data binding in `ListView`.

Comment: Look up, i have added ListView, but i can't translate , in resx i have translation these words: Pierwsze Spotkanie etc

Comment: @J.J, try to remove `resource:TranslateExtension` from your bindings, directly binding it like `{Binding nazwa}`, here your strings are directly added into list.

Comment: I know, but i want to translate this. So if i will do {Binding nazwa} word be that same like in list

Comment: @J.J, sorry, I don't think you can directly translate like normal control outside of `ListView`, but you can try to bind with converters, in the convert you can translate for localization.

Comment: How exactly do this?  {Binding Converter=resource:Translate nazwa} like this?

Comment: @J.J, found a discussion for this issue [Localization in a ListView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91998/localization-in-a-listview), there is sample code you may take a look. If you find this answer helpful, could you please mark this answer? Many thx!

Comment: Thanks, but do you know whats inside <ISettingsManager>() in code ?

Comment: @J.J, it's the interface that OP defined for the use of dependency service, I think it's not related to your case, directly check the marked answer.